# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DMatrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, xgboost

I tried all possible solution, but still getting this error, already installed all dependent libraries.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

from tqdm import tqdm
import xgboost as xgb

d_train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, label=y_train)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DMatrix'
```

Comment: `xgboost` is not imported properly. If you have xgboost.py file in the same directory, try renaming it.

Comment: Already tried but still getting error.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling `xgboost` using `pip`? Also what is the version of `xgboost` that you have?

Comment: I resolved the issue while reinstalling xgboost, thanks

Comment: I had the same issue. I also could fix this by simply pip reinstalling xgboost.

Answer (score 0):

You can force upgrade of XGBoost with:

```
python -m pip install xgboost --user --upgrade pip
```

This fixed it for me.